# Posicionamento em colunas no flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, layout-responsivo

Eu tenho o seguinte código no flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 40,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Text("A"),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("B"),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Text("C"),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Estou com um problema para posicionar os `widgets` na coluna. Pois, todos ficam na mesma posição em sequencia. Por exemplo; "center" ou "start" eu queria que o A ficasse no topo, o B no centro e o C no fundo. Alguém sabe dizer se é possivel fazer isso com as colunas? Ou eu teria que usar outro widget? Se sim, qual? pq o stack "resolve" o problema mas ele fica pouco responsivo e eu queria uma solução mais responsiva para o problema, bom é isso.

Answer (score 4):

As propriedades que permitem posicionar os elementos na coluna são a `mainAxisAlignment` (alinhamento no sentido principal do widget, que nesse caso é vertical por ser uma coluna) e a `crossAxisAligment` (alinhamento no sentido "cruzado" do `widget`, que nesse caso é horizontal já que uma coluna cresce na vertical). Para o seu problema, você pode utilizar o enum `MainAxisAlignment` e selecionar o `spaceBetween`. Ele divide o espaço vazio igualmente entre os elementos da coluna.

**Exemplo:**

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Text("A"),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text("B"),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Text("C"),
    )
  ],
)
```

Documentação da classe `Column`:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html

Documentação do enum `MainAxisAlignment`:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment-class.html

Comment: Thanks, ajudou bastante

Comment: @HiranJúnior não esqueça de marcar as respostas como 'aceitas', caso responderem sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Também tem o método Stack que você consegue posicionar cada elemento onde quiser
Aqui vai alguns exemplos:
Fonte: Medium.com

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    BottomWidget(),
    MiddleWidget(),
    TopWidget(),
  ],
),
```

[image: Top / Middle / Bottom]

Pode posicionar e dimensionar cada elemento:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    // Max Size
    Container(
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 300.0,
      width: 300.0,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.pink,
      height: 150.0,
      width: 150.0,
    )
  ],
),
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]